# How to understand cpu family/model/stepping fields in /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, cpu

I have following in `cpuinfo`:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 15
model       : 107
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5600+
stepping    : 2
```

According to Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlon_64_X2) there are two kinds of 5600+ -- one of 90nm technology, another of 65nm. How can I understand which one I have? There seem to be no direct correspondence between contents of `cpuinfo` and info on Wikipedia page.

AMD site seems to use some other naming scheme for processors too.

How can I map values of `family`, `model` and `stepping` from cpuinfo to the data available on Wikipedia/AMD?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://kevinclosson.wordpress.com/2007/01/04/using-the-cpuid1-linux-command-for-in-depth-processor-information/) page suggest that the [cpuid](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=cpuid) tool may be able to list more in-depth details of your cpu.

One of the lines it lists as an output is

> (simple synth) = AMD Dual Core Opteron (Italy/Egypt JH-E1), 940-pin, 90nm

So I'd either try that tool or have a look for it in whatever package manager your version of Linux uses.